# ExpressionEngine Control Panel SSL HTTPS Issue

Tags: control-panel, htaccess, ssl, themes, js

I have an issue with the HTTPS header for the ExpressionEngine control panel where the JS is being disabled. It keeps generating error messages where HTTP is being loaded over HTTPS (see below):

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://domain.com/sitebox/?/cp/homepage' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://domain.com/sitebox/?S=0&D=cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,sortable,dialog,button&plugin=ee_interact.event,ee_broadcast.event,ee_notice,ee_txtarea,tablesorter,ee_toggle_all,nestable&file=react/react.min,react/react-dom.min,json2,underscore,cp/global_start,cp/form_validation,cp/sort_helper,cp/form_group,cp/modal_form,cp/confirm_remove,cp/fuzzy_filters,components/no_results,components/loading,components/filters,components/filterable,components/toggle,components/select_list,fields/select/select,fields/select/mutable_select,fields/dropdown/dropdown&v=1557994073'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
?/cp/homepage:1

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://domain.com/sitebox/?/cp/homepage' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://domain.com/sitebox/?S=0&D=cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&file=cp/global_end&v=1557994052'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

The base and site URLs have been updated to cater for HTTPS. Also, the SSL is being forced in the .htaccess file and the themes URL should pick up the protocol using the PHP rule below—

```
// Declaring site variables
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$protocol = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$base_url = $protocol . $domain;

// Theme URL
$config['theme_folder_url'] =  $base_url . "/". $themes_folder;
```

The basic troubleshooting has been covered but not having much success.

Can anyone suggest a way around this please?

Comment: Have you tried just hard coding those values in your config (with the https protocol) instead of trying to detect them via PHP? Depending on your server setup, sometimes the `HTTPS` value isn't set at all

Comment: Hi @jrothafer thanks for the reply. I updated the **$protocol variable to equal 'https://'** but the same things occur. The base, site and themes URLs do match loading under to 'https://'. It's mainly the **themes script that won't under 'https://'**. The ExpressionEngine assets were uploaded from a local environment without having a 'https://' or SSL certificate. Would it be best to do a complete fresh EE installation or could the 'http://' URLs be updated in the database? Not sure is this a cache or configuration issue.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I'm also experiencing it and have tried setting HTTPS in a million places, to no joy

Answer (score 0):

Your site will load those JavaScript assets from the Control Panel via the `cp_url` setting. Try setting that:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/system-configuration-overrides.html#cp_url

```
$config['cp_url'] = 'https://domain.com/sitebox/';
```

That may not be the exact one, but this isn't a themes path issue, it's a CP path issue. Also check it in your CP settings, as you can set it there as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated the $config['cp_url'] to the admin link and both the variable and CP setting link match. However, the JS are still generating the **mixed content errors for the JS scripts.** I tried locating the JS raw files to see if the http:// references can be updated externally but it looks that all the assets are compressed. Is there a file location where all the control panel JS assets can be edited?

Comment: A controller generates that output, finding the raw files won't help. I'm not sure where something is set wrong, but this is really just a setting issue somewhere. Double check your Control Panel settings, and go over the system configuration variables, and triple check everything is set to `https`. And clear your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with loading js resources on every single EE project I've worked on (5 at this point) and every time I've had to contact the server host and have them whitelist an action in mod_security. Check your network headers and see if you're getting any 500 status errors.